# Using random number in an object constructor

Tags: java, random

How do I use a random number in my Fighter constructor? I want it to show me 3 random parameters from this one object.

```
    Fighter Lucas = new Fighter (2, 4, 7);
```

earlier i made this random for 3 different methods:

```
    Random rand = new Random ();

     public int m = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do here?  Do you want to feed 3 random numbers, perhaps in some range, into your `Fighter` constructor, or something else?

Comment: For 3 random numbers, you would call `rand.nextInt` 3 times.

Comment: `Fighter Lucas = new Fighter (rand.nextInt(9) + 1, rand.nextInt(9) + 1, rand.nextInt(9) + 1);`

Comment: I want to implement 3 random numbers instead of 2, 4, 7 into my Fighter constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much as you have shown, you call `rand.nextInt(max) + min` either seperately or inline. It's better to follow Java naming conventions (`Lucas` looks like a class name), so something like

```
Random rand = new Random();
int a = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
int b = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
int c = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
Fighter example1 = new Fighter(a, b, c);
```

**or** inline like

```
Fighter example2 = new Fighter(rand.nextInt(9) + 1, rand.nextInt(9) + 1, 
        rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
```

Both examples will construct a `Fighter` with three random numbers generated in the range `1` to `9` (inclusive).

Comment: `rand.nextInt(9) + 1` results in numbers in the range 1 to 9 inclusive, it will never be 10.

Comment: @Nevay Thank you so much, it's the weekend - should have double checked.